# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int'

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
class Solution {
    private:
    void make_zero(vector<vector<int> >& matrix,vector<pair<int,int>>v,int n,int m)
    {
        for(auto i:v)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                matrix[i.first][j]=0;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                matrix[j][i.second]=0;
            }
        }
    }
public:
    void setZeroes(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        
        int n=matrix.size();
        int m=matrix[0].size();
        vector<pair<int,int>>v;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j]==0)
                {
                    v.push_back({i,j});
                }
            }
        }
        make_zero(matrix,v,n,m);
    }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question** - do not just put code in the question and an error message in the title. This is not a debugging service; you should try to [figure out the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and then ask a question - starting with a question word like "why" or "how", and ending with a question mark - about exactly what you need to know from us. Also, read [mre] and include any required headers, `using` statements etc. in the example code, and indicate what version of C++ is needed.

Comment: i goes up to n in setzeroes and j goes up to n in make_zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` and `m` are swapped around in `make_zero()`, you confused the row and column dimensions.